# error when link mysql from qt5

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, mingw

I created makefile from .pro file in source code, then nmake and generated qsqlmysql.lib file, after added Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(qsqlmysql) into my code, and added qsqlmysql.lib and libmysql.lib into my project, I got the following error when building:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external "struct QStaticPlugin const __cdecl
>   qt_static_plugin_qsqlmysql(void)"
>   (?qt_static_plugin_qsqlmysql@@YA?BUQStaticPlugin@@XZ)，the symbol is
>   referenced in "public: __cdecl
>   StaticqsqlmysqlPluginInstance::StaticqsqlmysqlPluginInstance(void)"
>   (??0StaticqsqlmysqlPluginInstance@@QEAA@XZ)

I spent half a day, still couldn't solve the problem. For your reference, I paste the link command as follows,

/OUT:"H:\Market\freechartgeany-x64\freechartgeany-1.1.0\x64\Debug\FreeChartGeany.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /DYNAMICBASE "OpenGL32.lib" "Qt5PlatformSupportd.lib" "qwindowsd.lib" "Qt5OpenGLd.lib" "Qt5AxBased.lib" "Qt5AxContainerd.lib" "Qt5Cored.lib" "Qt5Guid.lib" "Qt5Multimediad.lib" "Qt5Networkd.lib" "Qt5Sqld.lib" "Qt5Widgetsd.lib" "qtmaind.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "shell32.lib" "uuid.lib" "ole32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "ws2_32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "imm32.lib" "winmm.lib" "winspool.lib" "msimg32.lib" "Qt5MultimediaWidgetsd.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"H:\Market\freechartgeany-x64\freechartgeany-1.1.0\x64\Debug\FreeChartGeany.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"x64\Debug\FreeChartGeany.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"I:\Qt\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.1\qtbase\lib" /LIBPATH:"I:\Qt\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.1\qtbase\plugins\sqldrivers" /LIBPATH:"I:\Qt\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.3.1\qtbase\plugins\platforms" /LIBPATH:"I:\Mysql\lib" /TLBID:1

Comment: maybe this: https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/issues/2340  or this https://forum.qt.io/topic/34969/static-link-q_import_plugin-qico-unresolved-external-symbol or https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-48415   when you get an error, take the unique parts of it and google.. I found those links by googling for struct QStaticPlugin const __cdecl qt_static_plugin_qsqlmysql

Comment: Thank you xaxxon. I visited the links provided by you, but it seems they can not solved my problem. In my project, I can link other qt plugin statically, not qsqlmysql.lib(i build this static lib from source). By the way, mysql version is 5.5.11 winx64. my qt source is 5.3.1

Comment: post the actual linker command being used that gives the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem in the following way,

in qt4.8.4, when you link qsqlmysql statically, you should write:

```
Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(qsqlmysql)
```

but in qt5.3.1, the name changed, you should write the macro as following:

```
Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(QMYSQLDriverPlugin)
```

That's why i always get a unresolved external... error. After change the name, i can link mysql successfully.